# How to import text from a text file "AS IS" and justify it?

Tags: formatting, listings, text, justification

I would like to import text from a .txt file as is, and have it be automatically wrapped and justified.
What I have done so far:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstset{ basicstyle=\ttfamily }
\lstinputlisting[breaklines=true]%
{./TEXTFILE.txt}
\end{document}
```

... I get something like that:

[image]

It looks decent, but I need it fully justified! How can I do that?
Here, the text file:

```
 We have three pairwise distinct values t0, t1, t2 from which we'll
 construct φ0, φ1, φ2 the Lagrange basis for degree 2 polynomials,
 associated with t0, t1, t2. Those three functions φ0, φ1 and φ2 Are 3
 polynomials of degree 2 built as follows : Here are our points t0, 
 t1, t2 the first polynomial φ0 is a degree 2 polynomial such that
 φ0(t0) = 1, φ0(t1) = 0 and φ0(t2)=0 We can draw this φ0 and we can
 even write a formula for φ0 since it is zero at t1 and t2, so we can
 write it as (t-t1)*(t-t2) and I want it to be equal to 1 at t0 so I
 divide it by (t0-t1)*(t0-t2). So we get the formula for φ0 Likewise I
 can build the polynomial φ1, degree 2 polynomial such that φ1(t0)=0
 φ1(t1)=1 φ1(t2)=0 So here is the polynomial φ1 and again we have a
 formula for φ1 which is (t-t0)*(t-t2) to get 0 at t0 and t2 and I want
 it to equal 1 at t1 so I divide it by (t1-t0)*(t1-t2). Finally we can
 build φ2 of degree 2 such that φ2(t0)=0 φ2(t1)=0 φ2(t2)=1 and we get
 an analogue formula. I now claim that those 3 functions φ0, φ1, φ2 are
 a basis for the set of polynomials of degree 2 or less. Indeed we have
 three functions in P2 the set of degree 2 polynomials. The dimension
 of the space of degree 2 polynomials is 3. Why 3 ? Because if p is a
 degree 2 polynomial, write it a0+a1*t+a2*t^2. So {1, t, t^2} is the
 canonical basis for the degree 2 polynomials. There are 3 elements in
 this basis so the dimension of P2 is 3 Hence the only thing to check
 to get that φ0, φ1, φ2 are a basis is that those three functions are
 linearly independent, so I take 3 coefficients α0, α1, α2 and I write
 the linear combination α0*φ0+α1*φ1+α2*φ2 and suppose this equals 0. I
 have to show that this implies that all coefficients α0, α1, α2 are 0.
 To show this, it suffices to take t=t0 to get α0=0 t=t1 to get α1=0
 and t=t2 to get α2=0.
```

Please copy and paste it into a .txt file named "TEXTFILE.txt" to replicate my example.

Comment: use `\input` not `listings`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for your input. I changed it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried that,  but \input interprets the text, hence I get some errors since some things in the text are not formatted to LaTex standards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply input the text

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}

\begin{document}

\def\tmp{{%
\catcode`\{=12
\catcode`\}=12
\catcode`\%=12
\catcode`\\=12
\catcode`\^=12
\catcode`\_=12
\input{textfile.txt}%
}}
\tmp
\end{document}
```

I used lualatex here, to set  up Greek with pdflatex is possible but takes a bit more work.

Comment: Catcodes to the rescue!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I could have used `\@makeother` instead but....

Comment: I get a strong sense that I am about to learn something new...Never heard of `\@makeother`.  Looking it up, it seems to be an alternate way of saying `\catcode\`#1=12 `.  Is there more to it?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes no that is exactly what it is, but I should probably have used it, just as people usually use `\makeatletter` rather than `\catcode\`\@=11 ` as it's a bit more readable.

Comment: Thanks.  Good to know.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you very much for your response! +1 The code works well. Two more questions: 1. What if I have much more non-latex-conformal input: Would I have to always create a catcode for every case? That's what I liked about \lstinputlisting. It just did not care about the input. I need it in a correct formatting....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Second question: How can I avoid the indent at the beginning?

Comment: @henry it's a paragraph, so will do whataver settings you have, `\parindent=0pt` and `\parskip=\baselineskip` if you want no indent and a line space between paragraphs for example

Comment: @henry there are really rather few characters in latex that require special processing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you so much for your help ! Do you know if I can find a list somewhere of those special characters that need extra treatment?

Comment: @henry latex verbatim uses this list `\def\dospecials{\do\ \do\\\do\{\do\}\do\$\do\&%
  \do\#\do\^\do\_\do\%\do\~}`

Comment: @henry so you could replace my catcode list by `\let\do\@makeother \dospecials` except you want a normal space here so then you would need `\catcode\`\ =10 ` to put that back.